# How to call BindingNavigator1. Add button / or make hotkey for it

Tags: .net, vb.net, visual-studio-2008

I use BindingNavigator1 that has ADD ROW / DELETE ROW buttons. However, I want to make my own *bigger* button with hotkey alt+a.

How to call BindingNavigator1. AddNewItem button from my button / or make hotkey for it?  There is no existing method..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `BindingNavigator` is just a graphical interface to the `BindingSource` component. You should call `AddNew` directly on the `BindingSource` itself, not through the `BindingNavigator`. Assuming that the `BindingSource` property of the `BindingNavigator` is set to `theBindingSource`, you should do that :

```
Private Sub MyOwnBiggerAddButton_Click(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs) Handles MyOwnBiggerAddButton.Click
    theBindingSource.AddNew()
End Sub
```

It is exactly equivalent to clicking the `AddNewItem` button on the `BindingNavigator`.